# How Do I Embed A CSV File into an IOS App? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, csv, swiftui

I am a beginner amateur so go easy on me.

I am using this to get my csv file:
let csvFile: CSV = try! CSV(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/joedodson/Documents/classroomappstuff/appproject/appproject/mondaybruh.csv")

and then I parse it in the swift project.

HOWEVER, this only works for me on my computer.

For someone else, they get a "no such file or directory" ERROR

So how do I store the CSV file in the app itself instead of getting it from my computer?

THANKS!

Comment: You need to store it in your app’s bundle. Although this is for an text file the principle is the same for any file https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/loading-resources-from-your-app-bundle